# Limit for bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops

I have problem with mass creation dummy files and directories.
I want to create something like this:

```
dummy_directory_1/dummy_file_1
dummy_directory_2/dummy_file_2
dummy_directory_3/dummy_file_3
```

using loop:

```
for(( i=1; $i <=1000; i++ )); do 
   mkdir $(date --date="$i day ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S); 
   touch $(date --date="$i day ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)/$(date --date="$i day ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)_file; 
done
```

Not all file are being created because I get following errors:

```
touch: cannot touch `20140211230556/20140211230556_file': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch `20131105230559/20131105230559_file': No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch `20130529000604/20130529000604_file': No such file or directory
```

Do you know if bash/linux has some limits for file creation? I had similar problem when I made script for searching many files using grep.
If i change loop `$i<=10` it works.
Please help.

Comment: Yes, by the way, there _are_ typically directory size limits (which vary by filesystem, so there's no one right answer about exactly where they are). You might hit them later -- but fixing the race condition by only calculating the name once is a good first step.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your code only works if the two `date` calls generating the name of the directory are executed within the same second, if that happens to change inbetween you end up with two different values for the direcory name.

Try to store the value in a variable first:

```
for(( i=1; i <= 1000; i++ )); do
    name=$(date --date="$i day ago" +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
    mkdir -p "$name" &&
    touch "$name/${name}_file" ||
    break
done
```

Comment: You might even want to change this to `mkdir && touch` or `mkdir || break` in case OP really does hit some limit and `mkdir` starts failing.